# Javascript submits one parenthesis instead of json stringified

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem. Even though I use JSON.stringify, my script still submits only "{", instead of a whole json object. This is the way I do it:

```
var value = {};
value['param_1_'] = {};
value['param_1_'].senderId = "de109s1e-1215-416a-98c7-6212e55da36a";
value['param_1_'].originatorId = "be30s61e-2s8d-4f61-9sc1-621fed5cw36a";
value['param_1_'].endpointId = "list-of-items";
submitform.createChild({
    tag: "input",
    type: "text",
    cls: "x-hidden",
    name: "data",
    id: "data",
    value: JSON.stringify(value)
});
submitform.dom.submit();
```

In the console I see, that my script submits just "{" instead of `value` object stringified. Why is that?

Comment: if you are first inputting this stringified json in a text input, then the case might be that the double quotes present in that string are causing confusion for the input tag. something like `<input value="{"param_1": {}}"` etc

so, it breaks at the first pairing double quote

Comment: No, I do it just in code. I do not do it manually.

Comment: that may not matter. As per my understanding, you are creating a new `input` here and setting its value as the stringified json. Hope you understood my point. values containing double quotes inside input tags may break at finding the first double quote.

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Will check it in a minute

Comment: comment out this line
`submitform.dom.submit();` and then inspect element to check the value in the input box.

Comment: You were right, Mike. I inspected the dom and see that the whole problem is in double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the problem is due to double quotes in stringified JSON, one way to solve it is to use `encodeURIComponent` function on `JSON.stringify(value)`. Then, you will need to use `decodeURIComponent` before trying to parse the JSON on the other end.